# what causes an NFS mount to drop to vers=3 instead of 4?

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

In RHEL 7.9, there are a handful of directories in `/etc/exports`.  On the nfs clients, they are all mounted as `vers=4.1` except for one which gets mounted as `vers=3` and `mountproto=udp` instead of tcp.

What can cause this and is there a way to troubleshoot this?  Is there a log file that can be looked at with NFS that details the operations happening and what decisions either the nfs-server or nfs-client is making when an nfs connection is being made, as to why it decides to drop to version 3?

Comment: It seems to me that NFSv4 requires physical paths in `/etc/exports` (and they are more like "access control list" than separate shares). Mounting a share that uses a (server-side) symlink falls back to NFSv3 when allowed. This is solely from my observations, I may be wrong; but please see if there are symlinks involved.

Comment: there were no symlinks involved.  On the nfs-server it mounts `/scratch` via uuid in `/etc/fstab` and that is one XFS partition on a 1tb SSD connected via SAS.  There was no problem there.  It was just that path in `/etc/exports` which was among ~5 others that only `/scratch` on the nfs-clients were mounted as vers=3.  I changed nothing, rebooted everything, all is well now at vers=4.1.